# Refcursor value is invalid/Bigger type length than Maximum/Protocol violation

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am  getting the following error randomly when trying to exceute queries from SQL Workbench

```
   Refcursor value is invalid  
   Bigger type length than Maximum  
   Protocol violation
```

and also when I try to run queries from my java code

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Refcursor value is invalid  
    java.sql.SQLException: Bigger type length than Maximum  
    java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
```

Above errors started occuring suddenly ,before it was working fine. DB is oracle and jar file is ojdbc14.jar

Is there any issue with the driver? or something else.Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with jar file.Replaced with latest version.